# Javascript calculation from form data returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm fairly new to JS and I think there's a problem with my code in the parts where I'm using Javascript for arithmetic. If someone could show me where I went wrong I'd be very grateful! Currently, everything works except it returns NaN when the calculate button is clicked.

HTML:

```
<form>
AGE:<br><input id="Age" data-wrapper-class="inputBox" type="text" name="Age"><br>
</form>

<form>
HEIGHT (FEET):<br><input id="Feet" data-wrapper-class="inputBox" type="text" name="Feet"><br>
</form>

<form>
HEIGHT (INCHES):<br><input id="Inches" data-wrapper-class="inputBox" type="text" name="Inches"><br>
</form>

<form>
WEIGHT (POUNDS):<input id="Pounds" data-wrapper-class="inputBox" type="text" name="Pounds"><br>
</form>

<button id="calcButton" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b">Calculate BMR</button>
</div>

<div id="resultsInfo">
<p id="results"></p>
</div>
```

Javascript / jQuery:

```
$("#calcButton").click(function() {
var age = document.forms["Age"]; 
var feet = document.forms["Feet"];
var inches = document.forms["Inches"];
var wip = document.forms["Pounds"];
var feetInches = feet * 12;
var heightInches = feetInches + inches;
var weightMen = 6.23 * wip;
var heightMen = 12.7 * heightInches;
var ageMen = 6.8 * age;
var one = 66 + weightMen;
var two = one + heightMen;
var menBMR = two - ageMen;
$("#Calculator").hide();
parseFloat(document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = menBMR);
$("#resultsInfo").show();
});
```

Comment: you need to get the elements `.value` ... and ensure they are a `Number`

Comment: There's no reason to put each `<input>` element in its own `<form>`; in fact that's weird.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm pretty new to all this, I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: Change input type = "text" to input type="number"

Comment: Hey Jaromanda, your answer did the trick, I really appreciate it. If you'd like to officially answer this I'll select it as the one :).

Comment: Rachel, good catch, will do!

Comment: http://jsbin.com/deracofuqe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Danny you're welcome... But I'm glad you accepted nicknish's answer :)

Comment: @Danny menBMR works better if you add Math.floor http://jsbin.com/gogiwajeza/edit?js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jaromanda mentioned, you need to ensure the values are actually a `Number` value. Once they're a number type then you can do arithmetic operations on them. Here's why this matters:

```
var str = "12"  // Number value
var num = 12  // String value
console.log(str * 2)  // 1212
console.log(num * 2)  // 24
```

In your code example, it looks as if you used inputs that are gathering the `type="text"` which means the values that you get from it would give you a String value. You can convert them to a number using `parseInt` or `parseFloat`, or you can change the HTML input type to `type="number"`, I believe.

Comment: Well, they snooze they lose, I guess I'll vote yours best. Thanks for taking the time!